# Is a submodule of a semisimple module $\bigoplus_{i\in I}X_i$ of the form $\bigoplus_{i\in K}X_i$ for some $K\subseteq I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $X$ be a semisimple module,
i.e., $X=\bigoplus_{i\in I}X_i$
where $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of simple submodules of $X$,
and let $W$ be a submodule of $X$.

Then there is a subset $J$ of $I$ that is maximal with respect to the property
$W\cap\sum_{i\in J}X_i = \{0\}$,
and it follows that $X$ and $W$ satisfy
\begin{equation*}
X = W\oplus\bigoplus_{i\in J}X_i.
\end{equation*}
(See e.g. [page 438](https://books.google.nl/books?id=t6N_tOQhafoC&pg=PA438&dq=hungerford+module+438&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi35ZLqpPrhAhVJYVAKHS3SBbwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=hungerford%20module%20438&f=false) in Hungerford's book "Algebra".)

But is it also true that
\begin{equation*}
W = \bigoplus_{i\in K}X_i
\end{equation*}
for some subset $K$ of $I$ (e.g. $K=I\setminus J$)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is "no",
and that the following provides a counterexample.

For simplicity,
let $X$ be a free module over the ring $\mathbb{R}$,
let $\{x_1,x_2\}$ be a basis of $X$,
and let 
$X_1=\mathbb{R}x_1$
and
$X_2=\mathbb{R}x_2$.
Then $X$ is semisimple and satisfies
\begin{equation*}
X = \bigoplus_{i=1,2}X_i.
\end{equation*}
Let $W=\mathbb{R}(x_1+x_2)$.
Then $W$ is a submodule of $X$,
but for no subset $K$ of $\{1,2\}$ does it satisfy
\begin{equation*}
W = \bigoplus_{i\in K}X_i.
\end{equation*}